# React native interval state not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-native

interval function in state change not working help me please.

state not change

```
function Home({ route, navigation }) {
const [ marker, setMarker ] = useState(0);

_stropeText = () => {
  if (marker == 0){
   setMarker(marker => 1);
  } else {
   setMarker(marker => 0);
  }
}

React.useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      setInterval(_stropeText, 500);
    });
    return () => {  };
  }, [navigation]);
}
```

https://snack.expo.io/Hbedd4HVh

Comment: Please show all relevant code

Comment: I updated my question and added the codes. Thank you

Comment: is `setLoading` defined? Are you sure the navigation listener is firing? How are you testing whether marker gets changed or not?

Comment: yes defined. console.log(marker)

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/Hbedd4HVh

Answer (score 0):

You [have a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on `marker` value, add it to `useEffect` dependency array, or use a reference with `useRef` hook.

Also, you passing a callback to `useState`, it makes [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), which is not the case here.

```
function Home({ route, navigation }) {
  const [marker, setMarker] = useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const _stropeText = () => {
      if (marker === 0) {
        setMarker(1);
      } else {
        setMarker(0);
      }
    };
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      setInterval(_stropeText, 500);
    });
    return () => {
      /*remove listener*/
    };
  }, [navigation, marker]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using useState hooks, the set function accepts one parameter, the value you want to set.

```
_stropeText = () => {
  if (marker == 0){
   setMarker(1);
  } else {
   setMarker(0);
  }
}
setInterval(_stropeText, 500);
```

**Update**:

according to the snack you provided, the `setLocation` function is asynchronous, so you are trying to display the new value of location before it has been set. You need an effect that responds to the change in value of the `location` variable to display the new value. E.g.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  alert(location)
}, [location])
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not updating

Comment: can you please share all of your code, esp. where setMarker is defined, and how you are displaying marker (or testing that it is getting updated)?