# React native state not updating function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React native state not updating. Location in alert returns empty.
Help me please

```
function Home({ route, navigation }) {

const [location, setLocation] = useState('');

const _appStart = () => {
_location();
}

const _location = () => {
setLocation("Konum Ekle");
alert(location);
}

React.useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
_appStart();
});
```

Comment: Setting state is asynchronous, so it won't be updated by the time your `alert` runs. It will be updated on the next render though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React native interval state not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161793/react-native-interval-state-not-updating) It seems you have asked similar two question in the same time

Comment: I need to get it inside the function render also appears

Comment: Where you are setting state in your code?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const _location = useCallback(()=>{
    setLocation('Hi')
  },console.warn(location)
)
```

instead of

```js
const _location = () => {
  setLocation("Konum Ekle");
  alert(location);
}
```

Basically setState is asynchronous. So call your alert in callback of setLocation, so once setLocation is complete your alert will comes in action.